# what is ${wf:id()} meaning in HUE?

Tags: hadoop, hue

Recently,I'm trying to understand company's code in HUE, I'm quite confused with the "`${wf:id()}`" in **HDFS**. Can someone explain what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is ooze expression language function, `${wf:id()}` returns the workflow job ID for the current workflow job. Check [section 4.2.3 Workflow EL Functions](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2_Expression_Language_Functions) for detailed description.